# Erro ao executar lista dart

Tags: flutter, dart

estou tentando fazer uma lista em dart/flutter, porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao executar a tela do app.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe Repositório:

```
chamarGetGaiola(String usuario, String token) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(
  urlAPI + "/GaiolasDisponiveis?usuario=$usuario&token=$token",
  headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
);

if (response.statusCode.toString() == "200") {
  List<dynamic> retorno = json.decode(response.body);

  List<Gaiola> lista = List<Gaiola>();

  for (final item in retorno) {
    Gaiola novoItem = Gaiola();
    novoItem.GaiolaId = item["gaiolaId"];
    novoItem.Nome = item["nome"];
    lista.add(novoItem);
  }


  return lista;

  // print("Resposata usuário: $usuario $senha $token");

}
```

Classe da Gaiola:

```
class Gaiola {

int GaiolaId;
String Nome;

}
```

Classe para montar a lista.

```
import 'package:projeto/Caixa.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projeto/global.dart' as gv;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'Gaiola.dart';
import 'Repositorio.dart';

class Aspirar extends StatefulWidget {
String caixa;

 @override
 _AspirarState createState() => _AspirarState();
  }



    class _AspirarState extends State<Aspirar> {



     Repositorio repositorio = Repositorio();

     TextEditingController campoQtdAspirada = TextEditingController();
     Gaiola gaiola;




    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Gaiola> listaGaiola = repositorio.chamarGetGaiola(gv.usuarioLogado, 
    gv.token);

    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title:
          Text("Aspirar Caixa ${gv.codigoQrCodeCapturado.toUpperCase()}"),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffccffcc),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xff263238),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          gv.codigoQrCodeCapturado.toUpperCase(),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 25,
          ),
        ),
        Image.asset(
          "imagens/caixa.png",
          width: 240,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
          child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Quantidade Aspirada",
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xffccffcc)),
            ),
            controller: campoQtdAspirada,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            child: DropdownButton<Gaiola>(
          items: listaGaiola.map((Gaiola gaiola) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<Gaiola>(
              value: gaiola,
              child: new Text(
                gaiola.Nome,
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (Gaiola value) {
            setState(() {
              gaiola = value;
            });
          },
          hint: Text(
            'Selecionar Gaiola',
          ),
          value: gaiola,
          underline: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffccffcc)),
            )),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          iconEnabledColor: Color(0xffccffcc),
          iconSize: 20,
        )),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 10),
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text(
              "Confirmar Aspiração",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            color: Color(0xffccffcc),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 16, 32, 16),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
            onPressed: () {
              print(
                  "Combo digitado: ${campoQtdAspirada.text}, GaiolaId: ${gaiola.GaiolaId}");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
     }
     }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Lendo novamente seu problema, acho que minha resposta não vai lhe ajudar muito. Melhore sua pergunta **EDITE** ela e coloque qual o tipo do retorno desse método `chamarGetGaiola` e coloque também o código de onde você usa o método.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro conforme solicitado, essa é a estrutura do app na qual estou tentando criar uma lista do retorno da minha API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltou apenas você tipar o retorno do seu método `chamarGetGaiola`, faça assim:

```
Future<List<Gaiola>> chamarGetGaiola(String usuario, String token) async {
  ...
}
```

Mas como seu método vai retornar um `Future` você irá precisar usar o `FutureBuilder`, modifique o seu combo de gaiolas da seguinte forma

```
Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: repositorio.chamarGetGaiola(gv.usuarioLogado, gv.token),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Container();

          return DropdownButton<Gaiola>(
          items: snapshot.data.map((Gaiola gaiola) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<Gaiola>(
              value: gaiola,
              child: new Text(
                gaiola.Nome,
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (Gaiola value) {
            setState(() {
              gaiola = value;
            });
          },
          hint: Text(
            'Selecionar Gaiola',
          ),
          value: gaiola,
          underline: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffccffcc)),
            )),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          iconEnabledColor: Color(0xffccffcc),
          iconSize: 20,
        );
        }
      )
    )
```

E assim você não precisará mais utilizar isso

```
List<Gaiola> listaGaiola = repositorio.chamarGetGaiola(gv.usuarioLogado, 
    gv.token);
```

Obs.: Não estou com Flutter no computador agora, então não cheguei a testar, talvez precise fazer alguma modificação.

**Porque utilizar FutureBuilder?**

Como a requisição feita a sua API é assíncrona e os dados serão recebidos em outro momento é necessário que seu método retorne um `Future<T>`.

O `FutureBuilder` vai aguardar essa chamada e assim que ela for finalizada, irá redesenhar o `Widget` que ele contém.

Fiz uma validação `if (!data.hasData) return Container();`, essa validação serve para que quando o `FutureBuilder` estiver aguardando a resposta da API ele desenhe um `Container` "nulo" assim não ocupando nenhum espaço e ficando imperceptível ao usuário.

Comment: Show de bola Matheus, estou só travado no método que você utilizou logo acima o .map. Quando chamei ele me da um erro dizendo error: The method 'Map' isn't defined for the class 'AsyncSnapshot'.

Comment: O `AsyncSnapshot` não tem mesmo o `Map`, me esqueci de uma parte hahaha Já ajustei, confira a resposta novamente, o certo é `snpshot.data`

Comment: Show de bola Matheus, deu certo a parte da tela do app, porém quando bate no meu repositório onde adicionamos o Future<List<Gaiola>>chamarGetGaiola(String usuario, String token) async ele da o seguinte erro:

type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Gaiola>>'

Cara me desculpe tá te enchendo com isso é que estou completamente frustrado por não ter conseguido arrumado isto e sem contar que estou iniciando rsrs.

Vou colocar a imagem do erro para você acima.

Comment: Cara deu certo aqui, em minha classe que estou trabalhando o que monta a lista adicionei após o snapshot.data.map o <DropdownMenuItem<Gaiola>> ficando da seguinte forma

items: snapshot.data.map<DropdownMenuItem<Gaiola>>((Gaiola gaiola) {...

Muito obrigado pela ajuda meu amigo, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Fez certo carinha, era o que eu iria sugerir!